# What browser is Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A202F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.120 Mobile Safari/537.36?

Tags: http, google-chrome, user-agent, safari

Is it Chrome, or Safari, and how should I be able to know?

I know a UA can be spoofed, but let's assume it isn't, as it's just from a typical user who would have no reason to - but I'm trying to debug an odd JS quirk and it'd be useful to know which browser they were using.

Thank you

Comment: `SM-A202F` is a Samsung smartphone product number: https://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/SM-A202FZBDSEE/ ; if not spoofed you then know what model was in the hand of your visitor.

Comment: That bit I'd figured out - it was whether they're using Chrome or Safari that foxed me.  Of course, I know there's no Android Safari app, officially anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the syntax for the User Agent header:

`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>`

In your case we have.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A202F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Still doesn't tell the full picture though, we need to know the browser engine (also known as a layout engine or rendering engine).

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/sm-a202f/

So in your case we have:

- **Software**: Chrome 91 (the software)
- **Layout Engine**: Blink
- **Software Type**: Web Browser
- **Popularity**: Average

[Blink](https://www.chromium.org/blink) is the name of the rendering engine used by [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/)

The browser is Chrome or chromium.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189418/15626554) answer useful.

Comment: Why do you doubt it's a typical user?  I'm 99% certain that it is

Comment: Additionally, could you explain to me why Safari is mentioned, if the browser used is Chome?  Thank you!

Comment: @Codemonkey Compatibility. Chrome (and Edge actually) use AppleWebKit.

Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @Codemonkey Also I doubt that it was a typical user because I don't expect a regular person to be using Chromium. If your users are engineers and developers, then I'd recant my doubt.

Comment: What about it says Chromium, as opposed to Chrome (which a significant portion of the public use)?

Comment: The layout engine is Blink

Comment: Chrome uses Blink as well.

Comment: @Codemonkey hm yeah I just looked it up you're right. I thought there was a slight difference. Sorry mate!